# How to create add data to fk column in database?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

new to coding and mysql so maybe I don't understand the fundamentals. I am trying to make a database for medical operations. I have a webpage where I enter the patient details and operation details and this generates an HTML page with the operation note partially populated with the data entered. I'm also saving the data enetered into 2 tables in mysql, patient_info table and operation table. I'm trying to make a foreign key in the patient_info table named operation_ID linked to the ID (auto-increment) in operations table so I know which patient had which operation. everytime I try entering data after making the fk, I'm getting "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`logbook_database`.`#sql-29f0_e55`, CONSTRAINT `link` FOREIGN KEY (`operations_ID`) REFERENCES `operations` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)". Where am I going wrong? I'm using phpmyadmin

I'm expecting like the ID in operations table to be copied automatically to the operations_ID column in the patient_info table since its the fk

Comment: The error you're encountering means that you are trying to insert a record into the patient_info table that references an operations table entry that does not exist. Ensure that there are records in the operations table beforehand

Comment: When the form is filled, I'm having records filled in both tables at the same time. Is it not possible to do this at the same time? and if not, can I have data entered in the operations table first then patient_info table using the same form submit? thank you

Answer (score 0):

To insert the row in the table that has FK (column linked to another table), you first must insert the row to the referenced table and get the ID of the new row. After that, you can use that ID to insert the data in the first table. Hope it will help.